# How can I initialize an object with data from two separate Alamofire requests?

Tags: ios, swift, foursquare, alamofire, swifty-json

Im trying to make a GET request to Foursquare's [Photos From a Venue](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/43695300f964a5208c291fe3/photos) and
Foursquare's [Explore](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/explore) at the same time. Right now (correct me if I'm wrong) I have two methods to make the request via Alamofire and convert the response to a JSON object using SwiftyJSON.

I can successfully update the UITableViewCell's labels to reflect the data using makeRequest() below, but can't update the UIImage for the background photo of each respective cell.

My problem is A) getting a usable photo URL, and B) Initializing "pin" while providing data from two separate requests. In order to initialize pin, I need to set all of the values. Im geting 90% of the values from one request, and 10% (the photo URL that I need to get) from another request. How do I initialize "pin" with data from two separate requests?

**makeImageRequest**:

```
    func makeImageRequest() {

    let venueID = "43695300f964a5208c291fe3"
    let firstURL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/\(venueID)/photos"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, firstURL, parameters: [
        "client_id" : foursquareClientID,
        "client_secret" : foursquareClientSecret,
        "v" : "20140806",
        "m" : "foursquare",
        "limit" : "10"
        ])
        .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(error)

            let jsonObj = JSON(data!)
            self.pins = []
            for obj in jsonObj["response"]["photos"]["items"].arrayValue {
                let photoURL = obj["prefix"]["suffix"].stringValue
                println("the photo url is\(photoURL)")
                let pin = Pin(title: obj["venue"]["name"].stringValue, openUntil: obj["venue"]["hours"]["status"].stringValue, address: obj["venue"]["location"]["address"].stringValue, ratingSignals: obj["venue"]["ratingSignals"].stringValue, ratingImage: UIImage(named:"Score8-5")!, venueImage: UIImage(named: "FloraGrubTestImage.jpg")!)
                self.pins.append(pin)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

and **makeRequest**

```
    func makeRequest(searchString: String) {

    let secondURL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, secondURL, parameters: [
        "client_id" : foursquareClientID,
        "client_secret" : foursquareClientSecret,
        "ll" : "37.71987,-122.470089",
        "query" : searchString,
        "radius" : "1000",
        "limit" : "10",
        "v" : "20140806",
        "m" : "foursquare"
        ])
        .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
            println(request)
            println(response)
            println(error)

            let jsonObj = JSON(data!)
            self.pins = []
            println(jsonObj)
            for obj in jsonObj["response"]["groups"][0]["items"].arrayValue {
                let pin = Pin(title: obj["venue"]["name"].stringValue, openUntil: obj["venue"]["hours"]["status"].stringValue, address: obj["venue"]["location"]["address"].stringValue, ratingSignals: obj["venue"]["ratingSignals"].stringValue, ratingImage: UIImage(named:"Score8-5")!, venueImage: UIImage(named: "FloraGrubTestImage.jpg")!)
                self.pins.append(pin)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I have a separate bindData() method in my UITableViewCell class. Does this make sense? Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:** An engineer I work with suggested that I make another request inside of the same method makeRequest and not bother with breaking it out into two separate methods. I also read a tutorial online that suggests a response router of some kind. Any suggestions on how I can refactor this code into one method?

**UPDATE #2:** I have renamed this question as I realize that the original question was not my real problem

Comment: What exactly is your problem with displaying the image? I do not see where you set the image, except for two static images `Score8-5` and `FloraGrubTestImage.jpg`.

Comment: @Rengers Score8-5 and FloraGrubTestImage.jpg are just placeholder images I have in xcassets and supporting files. I'm trying to parse a JSON response from the foursquare "Photos from a Venue" endpoint and convert that into a usable image URL. I will then take the image URL and use Haneke.

Comment: What is your actual problem then? Because the only code related to a photo that I can see is the `photoURL` variable, which you don't actually use anywhere.

Comment: My problem is A) getting a usable photo URL, and B) Initializing "pin" while providing data from two separate requests. In order to initialize pin, I need to set all of the values. Im geting 90% of the values from one request, and 10% (the photo URL that I need to get) from another request. How do I initialize "pin" with data from two separate requests?

Comment: @Rengers I renamed the question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to execute these request serially. First retrieve all the pins, and then retrieve all the photos. This is essentially what the other engineer advised.

If you fire off these requests in parallel, it will require a extra work to merge the responses, since you don't know which request will return first.

Now to merge the pins you need a way to uniquely identify each pin. If they have some ID, you can use that. Otherwise you have to rely on the sort order and index. Assuming each request returns the same pins in the same order.

After the first request returns, you have an array of pins. Then in the second request callback you can retrieve the matching pin from this array and update it with the new data.